# Javascript extract only the capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I need to extract an id from a string but I can't only the ID. I'm trying to user a pattern that works fine in Java, but in JS it yields more results than I like. Here is my code:

```
var reg = new RegExp("&topic=([0-9]+)");
```

When applying execute this against the string "#p=activity-feed&topic=1697"

```
var results = reg.exec("#p=activity-feed&topic=1697");
```

I was hoping to get just the number part (1697, in this case) because this was preceded by "&topic=", but this is returning two matches:

```
0: "&topic=1697"
1: "1697"
```

Can someone help me to get `["1967","9999"]` from the string `"#p=activity-feed&topic=1697&no_match=1111&topic=9999"`?

Comment: Just index the returned array like so: `var number = results[1];`. On a side note if you want more than one match from a string you'll need to include the `g` flag when constructing your regex.

Comment: "#p=activity-feed&topic=1697&no_match=1111&topic=9999".match(/topic=(\d*).*topic=(\d*)/).slice(1)

Comment: @JaredSmith's solution is probably the easiest, but you're facing a look behind situation. If you removed the parentheses from the regex you would just get the whole string and you could remove the `&topic=` portion.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. @JaredSmith your solution comes with a major problem: I don't know the position "&topic=..." might come, nor how many times does it appear.

Comment: @jcarias `reg = /&topic=(\d+)/g;while(m = reg.exec("#p=activity-feed&topic=1697&no_match=1111&topic=9999")) console.log(m[1]);` logs 1697 and then 9999. Works for any arbitrary number of matches and any position(s) in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the browser support is right for your use case, [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) can do all of the parsing for you:

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams('p=activity-feed&topic=1697&no_match=1111&topic=9999');
console.log(params.getAll('topic'));
```

Answer (score 0):

While Noah's answer is arguably more robust and flexible, here's a regex-based solution:

```
var topicRegex = /&topic=(\d+)/g; // note the g flag
var results = [];
var testString = "p=activity-feed&topic=1697&no_match=1111&topic=9999";
var match;
while (match = reg.exec(testString)) {
  results.push(match[1]); // indexing at 1 pulls capture result
}
console.log(results); // ["1697", "9999"]
```

Works for any arbitrary number of matches or position(s) in the string. Note that the matches are still strings, if you want to treat them as numbers you'll have to do something like:

```
var numberized = results.map(Number);
```